# Problema na acentuação ( -jar mysql)

Tags: java, windows, acentuação, jar

Olá,

Fiz um programa em Java que insere diversos textos em um banco de dados, rodando da minha maquina (Mac Os), tudo funciona muito bem.
Mas, colocando em uma VPS (Windows) para que o programa fique rodando 24/7, os acentos no Banco chegam bugados, como por ex:

```
"integrante do Ã�lbum "LadrÃ£o"
```

Estou rodando o programa via um .bat que contém apenas a linha:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JavaApplication27.jar"
```

Conexão via jdbc para um banco Mysql (de um Cpanel/Hospedagem) hospedado na Hostgator.

```
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://br934.hostgator.com.br:3306/"+DB+"?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8";
```

O banco de dados está com o charset em utf8mb4.

**O que é o programa?**

Ele bate numa API do Youtube, trazendo o titulo e descrição de diversos videos, e muitos contém caracteres especiais e até mesmo emoticons.

--

Em Resumo, 
Fiz um programa no NetBeans em Java, após compilado, quando eu rodo o .jar no Mac Os, ele funciona sem problema nenhum, porém quando rodo o mesmo .jar no Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard todos os acentos que vão pro INSERT INTO, ficam bugados no banco de dados, conforme o exemplo acima.

Como posso resolver o problema com a acentuação sendo inserida errada quando o programa está rodando no windows?

Comment: Por favor forneça mais informações através de [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/214302/edit) e leia sobre 
[Como Perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
e ainda a [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes que tipo de informação a mais é necessário?

Comment: Qual é o banco de dados utilizado e como você faz a conexão a ele?

Comment: MySQL, hospedado na Hostgator, conecto por jdbc

Answer (score 1):

Cara, não sei se te ajuda, mas dá uma olhada no teu banco e vê o "charset" dele (se é UTF-8 ou algum outro);

Tenta também usar HTML dentro do código Java (uma bela gambiarra, mas funciona).

Exemplo:

```
System.out.println("<html><meta charset="utf-8"/>Este é meu exemplo. Aqui todos os acentos funcionam hehehehehe</html>");
```

Saída:

Este é meu exemplo. Aqui todos os acentos funcionam hehehehehe

Comment: Estou trabalhando com o charset em utf8mb4 no banco.
Desta forma não funcionaria, eu pego títulos e descrições e adiciono no banco de dados, pra exibir em um site (PHP)

Comment: Acho que, então, não posso ajudar ainda. Comecei a pouco tempo a estudar bancos de dados e SQL :/

Comment: MySQL não suporta utf8mb4 ele usa ISO 8859-1 no lugar, o que gera as anomalias.